# Redshift : defining composite primary key

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table for which I want to define a composite primary key with two columns in redshift. I am having some trouble with create table syntax. Here is what I am trying to do :

```
Create table metrics  (
     id varchar(30),
     runtime timestamp,
     category varchar(30),
     location varchar(30))
primary key(id, runtime),
sortkey(runtime);
```

It is failing with a message :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"
```

Can anyone please help me figure out how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `primary key` constraint goes inside the parentheses containing the columns:

```
Create table metrics  (
     id varchar(30),
     runtime timestamp,
     category varchar(30),
     location varchar(30),
     primary key(id, runtime)
)
sortkey(runtime);
```

Comment: I tried like you mentioned. Create table worked fine. But I am receiving the following error when I try to load data into the table :  
Multiple primary keys are not allowed.

Comment: According to the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html), *composite* primary keys are allowed and the answer has the right syntax.  You cannot have multiple primary keys on a table, and neither your question nor my answer has multiple primary keys.