# How to ALTER TABLE in Amazon Redshift to set two columns as Primary Key?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I would like to alter table in Amazon Redshift, and put two columns as a composite Primary key?

I tried this code snippet:

```
ALTER TABLE tableNameHere ADD CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (col1);
```

But it worked just to set just one single primary key.

Then I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE tableNameHere ADD CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);
```

And I get an error:

```
Invalid operation: multiple primary keys for table "t_sim_data" are not allowed;
```

PS_1: I already read [Redshift : defining composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575554/redshift-defining-composite-primary-key) but in that question it is about creating not altering a table.

PS_2: I have other tables in our cluster where I can see that they have a composite (of two columns) primary key. So it is definitely possible to have a composite Primary Key in Amazon Redshift.

PS_3: I know the power of Redshift is in setting DistKey and SortKey, but I need to set a composite primary key for a table for a specific need.

Comment: You will need to `DROP CONSTRAINT` then `COMMIT`before you `ADD CONSTRAINT` again.

Answer (score 3):

1st drop the PK_1 constraint then
create the 2nd

```
ALTER TABLE tableNameHere DROP CONSTRAINT PK_1;
```

then

```
ALTER TABLE tableNameHere ADD CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);
```

Comment: Thanks! But still getting the same error: Invalid operation: multiple primary keys for table tableNameHere are not allowed;